# C# Linq Select&Except vs Where&All Performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I'm testing for get difference of two collections.

[image: Console Log]

Can you show me why `.Where` is faster than `.Except`?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class ADSASDCollection
{
    public GameObject gameO;
}

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<ADSASDCollection> list;
    public List<GameObject> gameList;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var time = DateTime.Now;
        var count = 100000;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            foreach (var o in list.Where(item => gameList.All(item2 => item2 != item.gameO)))
            {
            }
        }

        Debug.Log($"Time - {time - DateTime.Now}");
        time = DateTime.Now;
        
        var select = list.Select(item2 => item2.gameO).ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            foreach (var o in gameList.Except(select))
            {
            }
        }

        Debug.Log($"Time - {time - DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```

I want to get difference of two collections faster than I get it now.

I know `query` is faster, but I want to know why the `.Where` is faster than `.Except`

```
var query = (from a in gameList
             from b in list
             where a != b.gameO
             select a);
```

Comment: If that is all of your code, as you stated, both lists are empty and simple loops on these empty lists would likely always be faster than a more generalized operation like `.Except()`. If this isn't all of your code and you populate both lists somewhere, what are the element counts for each?  If less than a few 10s, simple loops may still be faster. If the counts increase much more than that you would likely see `.Except()` having better performance. Except populates a `HashSet<>` to support fast lookups, which would yield much better performance than sequential searches for large collections.

Comment: To put it another way, if `gameList` contains `N1` elements, and `list` contains `N2` elements, the *time complexity* of the simple loops would be `O(N1 * N2)`, while I believe the time complexity for the `.Except()` would be something between `O(N1 + N2)` and perhaps `O(N2 + N1 * Log(N2))`, depending on hash collisions.  For large collections, `.Except()` would be the clear winner.

Comment: Off course, the elements are not empty. Thank you for explain